# How do I add favorite/specific sites to the Firefox 3.6 jump list?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, jumplist

Using Windows 7 and Firefox 3.6: I have Firefox pinned to my taskbar, and would like to have some specific sites pinned to the icon's jump list. Is this possible, if so how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read, the developers of a program have to implement jumplist features beyond the basics of opening the program and closing it. You might notice that Internet Explorer has the ability you're talking about.

I guess the team at Mozilla hasn't gotten around to that yet.

In the meantime, you can use [Jumplist Extender](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/05/19/jumplist-extender-adds-windows-7-jumplists-to-programs-which-don/) to add your own things to a jumplist.

[image]

Comment: The thing about Jumplist Extender: does it run in the tray/background or is it a one time tweaker thing or what?

Comment: Woah, dude, that is **WICKED COOL**!!! It actually lets you get a jumplist on the CMD window; WOOHOO!!!  :)  @studiohack; it seems to be a one-time thing. I just made a jumplist for CMD.EXE and then exited the program, and my jumplist still works.

Comment: **SWEET**!!!! will give it a try!

Comment: It works awesome!!  I even got the site icons and added them, it looks so neat!

Comment: @studiohack Almost 9 years later, Jumplist Extender seems to be discontinued.  Are you using it anymore, or is there a good gratis replacement?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found is to write an html file with contents like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.google.com"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Change to whatever site you want, and name it something like google.html then `File->Open->Said file`. Now it will be in the jump list as recent, which you can then pin.

A crappy work around but it works.