# Is there a way to get Chatzilla in the Windows 7 "jumplist" for Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, jumplist, chatzilla

[Windows 7 has a feature called "Jumplists"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows7/products/features/jump-lists) which, in the Start menu, adds a kind of context menu alongside the selected app listing things such as files recently or frequently used with that app, and tasks the app can perform:

[image: Firefox Jumplist in Windows 7]

Often I use Firefox's add-on IRC client, Chatzilla but use Chrome for browsing. I have to start the Firefox browser, run Chatzilla from the menua, then close the browser again.

It seems this is exactly the kind of thing Jumplists are for. Is there a way to customize them in Windows 7? Or does Firefox offer a way to customize its own Jumplists?

Answer (score 0):

I did some messing around with the DOM Inspector add-on to find out the XUL pages that the IRC uses. <del>I have no perfect solution, but one of these two might do:</del>

<del>**Solution 1:** Set the homepage of Firefox to `chrome://chatzilla/content/chatzilla.xul`. This will automatically open the Chatzilla IRC client in a Firefox tab. The downside, of course, is the fact that the ChatZilla IRC client will be inside a Firefox tab, which means that the top part of the window will be Firefox (and take up some vertical space). Of course, you could hide the navigation bar and do some other tweaks to hide the top part of the window.</del>

<del>**Solution 2:** Set the homepage to `irc://`. This will automatically open the usual ChatZilla client but you will still have to close the Firefox window. But this does cut one step and therefore better than nothing.</del>

**EDIT:** I have found the perfect solution! (Windows instructions)

1. Right-click on the shortcut of your Firefox icon and go to Properties.
2. In the shortcut tab, Target field, ADD this to the END of the target: `-chrome "chrome://chatzilla/content/chatzilla.xul"` and press OK.

If you still want to use Firefox for regular web browsing, I would make this as a new shortcut. Or at the very least, change the name and icon of the shortcut to ChatZilla so you know what you are clicking on.

**EDIT2:** A quick search showed that you could simply use `-chat` at the end of the target. I suppose you would have already seen this, which means that you only wanted to know how to add it to the jumplists. You could try the [Jumplist Extender](https://superuser.com/questions/178145/how-do-i-add-favorite-specific-sites-to-the-firefox-3-6-jump-list).

Comment: Actually I did know about the `-chat` option and in fact I have an icon on the desktop set up that way to run Chatzilla. And I suppose it's on OK *workaround*, but for this question I wanted specifically to find a way to make use of the 'Jumplist' feature to be able to open either/both from the same Start menu item. Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: What about the Jumplist Extender link?

Comment: Jumplist Extender seems pretty nice, but it seems to only add to another Jumplist I wasn't aware of! Programs running with icons in the taskbar also have jumplists if you right-click on them. I was able to add a Chatzilla Task here, but not to the Firefox entry in the Start menu...